# Post image src to MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to post the content of an image element to my controller so I can store it in my database with the use of an  element.

The image src format is something like this:

> data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMUAAAEACAYAAAADarJDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAFCxJREFUeJzt3XuUnHV9x/HP9zuzu0kAEUKicqyGGsAbF41ELAm7syG7swmCye5ka22otF6rYqmKp3houng5R9GDtl4OwvFCC6e72QkihMwmZGc3IWop0SqXQ2qUtV6qyQZSkkAu83y//SM7usRNMjPP73l+z8x+X39yTr7PN+R57zO3fQYwxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMYlGvheYLhbctqDp1DNeMhspOosomE2qpxNRSxCghYFmENJQlJRxiAmHVfUQNLUXGuyh5u

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", $('#myImage').attr.src);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/default/upload/",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            //code after success
            alert("succes");
        },
        error: function (er) {
            alert(er);
        }
 });
```

and here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Upload(string image)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do Something");
}
```

My breakpoint is triggered but my image string just contains `undefined`

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Why would you send an image back to the controller that the controller sent to the client?

Comment: I'm only sending the image to the controller, not sending it back to the client. I'll try to update my question to clarify

Comment: But where did the image come from?

Comment: From the clipboard. I'm using javascript to paste any image in the users clipboard to an <img> tag on the site. When they press submit on my form, I then need to save the image they pasted as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from this line:

```js
data.append("image", $('#myImage').attr.src);
```

And the solution is:

```
data.append("image", $('#myImage').attr('src'));
```

or if you're using jquery version 1.6 or later:

```
data.append("image", $('#myImage').prop('src'));
```

> My breakpoint is triggered but my image string just contains `undefined`

That's because `$('#myImage').attr.src` returned `undefined`. Then, you sent the value to server. And of course, `image` caught `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

First you can post image src to controller as original string by removing `data:image/gif;base64;` from src string

Then you convert this base64 string to binary and save into database

```
byte[] imageBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(srcBase64String);
```